# Converting a file content into two dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file-io

Am new to PHP and am using php5.2, I need to convert a file content into a two-dimensional array, ie my file content will be

```
"Higher Studies" => "#",
"Symposiums" => "#",
"Conferences" => "#"
```

And my expected output is,

```
Array ( [Higher Studies] => # [Symposiums] => # [Conferences] => # )
```

PHP functions I tried to achieve this,

```
$values = file_get_contents($url);
echo $values;
$array = explode(",", $values);

$array = array(file_get_contents($url));

$array = file('http://localhost/test1.php');
```

And finally I am getting an answer like this,

```
Array ( [0] => "Higher Studies" => "#", [1] => "Symposiums" => "#", [2] => "Conferences" => "#" )
```

Is this the possible way we can read from a file or Is it possible to get a solution as like What I expected??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should read it via file, then go for each row, split and store in array

```
$array = array();
$values = file($url);
foreach ($values as $idx => $row)
{
    list($k, $v) = explode(' => ', $row);
    $k = trim($k, '"');
    $v = trim($v, '",');
    $array[$k] = $v;
}
print_r($array);
```

or you can do:

```
$values = file_get_contents($url);
eval('$array = array('.$values.');');
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Is eval() a good choice or splitting the contents as you said before can be good??

Comment: eval can be prohibited on some hosting systems, so it is better to do with file/split - but if you're sure about file contents, and server - eval will be faster

Comment: Yeah it works good. May be support will be prohibitted after some days too in my hosting right. So better to go with split? How can I split things like this.

Comment: In that am getting the output for values with **",**

Comment: Thanks Ilya Bursov. I have edited the answer as it works good for me.